# Send data from one table to another when instantiated django

Tags: django

What I want is that when creating an instance of the user object the name goes to another table called profile_data but I don't know how to do it, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to register a `signal`. You can find the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders)